# How to get values from Future<List> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I want to get value from sqflite database to a list in flutter.
Here is my model class

```
class Task {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String dateTime;

  Task({this.id, this.title, this.description, this.dateTime});

  
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id':id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'dateTime': dateTime,
    };
  }
```

This is databaseHelper class for insert and retrieve data.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._();
  static final DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper._();

  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await _createDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _createDatabase() async {
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'task.db'),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , title TEXT, description TEXT, dateTime TEXT)",
      );
    }, version: 1);
  }


Future<List<Task>> tasks() async {
 
  final Database db = await database;

  final maps = await db.query('tasks');

  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return Task(
      id: maps[i]['id'],
      title: maps[i]['title'],
      description: maps[i]['description'],
      dateTime: maps[i]['dateTime']
    );
  });
}



Future<void> insertTask(Task task) async {
  final db = await database;


  await db.insert(
    'tasks',
    task.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
}
}
```

When I use print(await tasks()) it shows [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task'] in console. is it a bug?. I want to know how to get values form database using task() function in DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: it's not a bug `Instance of Task` means that the List contains `Task` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use future builder, which requires future and will build whenever future's object changes.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use print(await tasks()) it shows [Instance of 'Task', Instance
> of 'Task'] in console. is it a bug?

It happens because you haven't overridden `toString()`. Without `toString()` you just get the default string conversion "*Instance of XXX*":

```
class Example {}

void main() async {
  print(Example());  // Instance of 'Example'
}
```

By overriding `toString()` you can customize the output:

```
class Example {
  @override
  String toString() => "My custom Example!";
}

void main() async {
  print(Task());  // My custom Example!
}
```

> I want to know how to get values form database using task()

The most common way in Flutter to await for a `Future<T>` is using the [`FutureBuilder<T>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget. It's very convenient because it can display a progress indicator (to let the user know that something is going on in the background) that will be replaced later by the actual data